# Using database stored lat/long to plot dynamically onto a Google Map

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, maps

I'm doing a website for a company that develops new housing estates. I have a database containing table of postcodes/latitudes/longitudes for each of the developments.

What I need to do is get those longitudes/latitudes plotted onto a Google Map within the page based on the search results returned by a function I've written. The above mentioned properties are available through the instances of the class

I've researched this long and hard but can't seem to find anything that will answer my actual question - I've looked at the Google Maps API and various other resources, the closest thing I've found is this: http://www.multiplottr.com which is in essence what I want to do except that the points will be pulled from the database and will have some kind of class/ID on them so that I can add hover and click functions as well as interactivity with other elements on the page

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Hi you may use like this

```
 function initialize() {
        var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo latitude from db ?> , <? php echo echo longtitude from db; ?> );
        var mapOptions = {
            center: fenway,
            zoom: 16,

            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        var image = '<?php echo $path;?>components/com_propertylist/images/Home.png';
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: fenway,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        // google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }
```

Comment: Theoretically could your fenway variable be a dynamic array which I could use to add the longitude/latitude of several points?

Comment: LatLng(lat,lng) is a function in Google maps API. It accepts only 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry I think maybe you misunderstand what I'm asking, if I had an array like:

`location[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
location[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);`

Would I be able to use this to plot several markers on the map?

Comment: Sure you can do it is better to iterate the array value of lat and lng and add the markers into a map

Answer (score 0):

Take the latitude / longitude values that are stored in your DB and plot them on the map using  the Google Maps api. The plots are often referred to as markers. That might help you during your research.

Essentially, you'll need to write JS using PHP...

Comment: I didn't know about the terminology ("markers") that will be quite helpful when researching in future I should think, and yeah I knew I'd need to write JS using PHP I just couldn't seem to find anything to actually tell me how I would plot onto the map programatically - thank you for your swift reply